# Purpose of -ms-filter in css

Tags: css

Do I really need to use -ms-filter CSS Opacity Properties? I want to run opacity for ie7 to ie11 browser and i used below mentioned css. I got to know that filter works for ie5-ie8 and -ms-filter is only for ie8. if both works for ie8 than what is the purpose of using -ms-filter.

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; /*Internet Explorer 8 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50); /*Internet Explorer 5, 6, 7, 8 */
opacity: 0.5; /* Modern browsers */
```

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx) says that:

> Sets or retrieves the filter or collection of filters that are applied
> to the object.
>
> [....]
>
> The -ms-filter attribute is an extension to CSS, and can be used as a
> synonym for filter in IE8 Standards mode. When you use -ms-filter,
> enclose the progid in single quotes (') or double quotes ("). Use
> commas (,) to separate multiple values, as shown in the Examples
> section.

The -ms-filter is supported in IE8+. It is added to make IE more standard complaint. Also check [Microsoft CSS Vendor Extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/08/microsoft-css-vendor-extensions.aspx)